# Delete N lines of file

Tags: python, file

I have the following .txt file:

```
28563868423
37832070256
49953540371
39723132411
48576892756
49159435134
49580970815
50007496483
8122645142
```

For example, I want to delete with the length of "id" (the first 3 lines).

But when I do that it deletes the first and fourth line.

```
id=[[''],[''],['']]

lines=[]
with open('Id.txt','r') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()

with open('Id.txt','w') as f:
    for number,line in enumerate(lines):
        if number not in [0,len(id)]:
            f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in [0,len(id)]` literally checks if it's the first or `len(id)`-th line. For the desired result, the check should be:

```
if number >= len(id):
    ...
```

or, even better, replace it with array slicing:

```
for line in lines[len(id):]:
    f.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks, the first variant worked. But the second however did not :>

Comment: @Marat's second solution is missing the colon in the slicing notation (indicating "from this index onwards") - it should be `lines[len(id):]`. As it is right now, it's selecting a specific row and iterating over its characters. I believe it's just a typo on Marat's part :)

Comment: @bot_der_4 - hyit is right, I missed the colon (yes, a typo). Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `[0, len(id)]` you're effectively creating a list with two items - 0 and `len(id)`. It seems you're interested in the range of numbers from 0 to `len(id)` - so `range(len(id))` would be what you're looking for.
If you are always interested in eliminating the first N rows, you could also simply check for row numbers that are equal or larger then `len(id)` - `if number >= len(id): ...`.

However, a more Pythonic and efficient solution would be to use list slicing. You can select all rows starting at `len(id)` with `lines[len(id):]`. See Python's [Introduction to Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) where the slicing notation is introduced.